# I would like to recreate the IF statement shown as a user defined function

Tags: excel, vba, if-statement, user-defined-functions

I have the below `IF OR` statement below, that does the job I want it to but I would prefer if I could create this as a user defined function,

Essentially, I have 2 columns of data, the columns will only ever have Red Amber or Green as their values, and I want the UDF to be able to look at both cells across the columns and return the worst case scenario, for example if one column is amber and one is green, the UDF would return Amber as that's worse than green

```
=IF(OR(AZ8="Red",AY8="Red"),"Red",IF(OR(AZ8="Amber",AY8="Amber"),"Amber","Green"))
```

This is what i have so far

```
Function CalculateOverallRAG(CellRef1 As Range, CellRef2 As Range,RAGStatus As String) As String

  If CellRef1 = "Red" Or CellRef2 = "Red" Then
    RAGStatus = "Red"
  ElseIf CellRef1 = "Amber" Or CellRef2 = "Amber" Then
    RAGStatus = "Amber"
  Else
    RAGStatus = "Green"
  End If

  CalculateOverallRAG = RAGStatus

End Function
```

Comment: So where is the problem? Can you show us what you have attempted so far?

Comment: Why would you need a UDF for this? Your formula looks fine to me.

Comment: No problem at all, formula works fine, im just starting out with UDF's so trying to get something i know works as an if statement into a UDF to help me understand them  a bit better

Comment: There is no need to pass `RAGStatus` as an argument, you can just `Dim` is within the function as a local variable. Other than that, your UDF looks just fine. Is it not doing what you want?

Comment: @brax unfortunately not, not quite sure what im doing wrong but i keep getting a Value error, the formula within excel looks like this
   

 `=CalculateOverallRAG(A1:B1)`

im thinking it doesn't like the cell selection?

Comment: Well, a range cannot equal a string... but that information (which you didnt include) should help someone make a loop for you.

Comment: Apologies for not including everything, i believed i did, thank you for your help so far :)

Answer (score 0):

The code OP presents looks to work fine. But what if the input was multiple cell range, not a single cell? Or what if a text literal like "Green" was passed instead of cell reference?

If you were to reveal a UDF to end-users, you need to make it safe for any possible input.

Here is an alternative I thought of, which involves tremendous validation. This specific case is obviously not worth it.

```vb
Option Explicit

Public Function CalculateOverallRAG( _
    ByVal Color1 As Variant, _
    ByVal Color2 As Variant _
) As Variant

    Dim ValidColor1 As Variant
    Dim ValidColor2 As Variant

    If Not TryConvertColorArg(Color1, ValidColor1) Then
        CalculateOverallRAG = CVErr(xlErrValue)
        Exit Function
    End If

    If Not TryConvertColorArg(Color2, ValidColor2) Then
        CalculateOverallRAG = CVErr(xlErrValue)
        Exit Function
    End If

    If ValidColor1 = "Red" Or ValidColor2 = "Red" Then
        CalculateOverallRAG = "Red"
    ElseIf ValidColor1 = "Amber" Or ValidColor2 = "Amber" Then
        CalculateOverallRAG = "Amber"
    Else
        CalculateOverallRAG = "Green"
    End If

End Function

Private Function TryConvertColorArg(ByVal Color As Variant, ByRef Out As Variant) As Boolean

    'Single Cell is acceptable
    If TypeOf Color Is Range Then
        If Color.Count = 1 Then
            Color = Color.Value
        Else
            TryConvertColorArg = False
            Exit Function
        End If
    End If

    'String value is acceptable
    If VarType(Color) = vbString Then
        Out = Color
    Else
        TryConvertColorArg = False
        Exit Function
    End If

    If Out = "Red" Or Out = "Amber" Or Out = "Green" Then
        TryConvertColorArg = True
    Else
        TryConvertColorArg = False
    End If

End Function
```